# Adding exception for a all() function in laravel

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a table with :         `Etudiant::create($request->all());`
But actually there is some field that I don't need from the requedt but I need them for another table; So I'm wondering if there is a function or something to add an exception to the `->all()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to whitelist fields:

`$request->only('valueField1', 'valueField2');`

or you may want to blacklist :

`$request->except('valueField', 'valueField1');`

Both not much safe enough tho.

I'd handle requests like this:

`$validated = $request->validate(['valueField' => 'required|validation_types']);`

Validated fields that you're wanting to use and then:

`Etudiant::create($validated);`

Note: For update case there is nullable field then use `array_filter($validated);` this will remove null fields and then `Etudiant::update($validated);`

Answer (score 1):

```
$request->only('val1', 'val2', ...);
```